# Plotting a grouped bar chart from two Excel sheets with a primary key?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, plot, analytics

I have two Excel sheets as follows:

[image: Sheet1]

[image: ٍSheet2]

I need to plot the count of each `Grade` (A, B, C,..) in every `Region` (Region1, Region2,..) in a grouped bar chart.

I loaded the two sheets using pandas as follows:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile("D:/Works.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
ds = xl.parse("Sheet2")
```

Then I merged the sheets in one dataframe:

```
data_set = pd.merge(df, ds, how='left')
```

The DataFrame `data_set` is replicated as:

```
data_set = pd.DataFrame({'Center_ID': ['E25007','E08003','E17020','E08004','E25007','E08035','E08614','E08026','E25023','E17006','E25007','E08004'],
 'Grade': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'F', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'F', 'C', 'B'],
 'Name': ['Jack','Eliana','Frank','Sheila','Irene','Celine','Sebastian','Teun','Silvia','Luis','Catalina','Patricia'],
 'Region': ['Region1',None,'Region4','Region3','Region1','Region2','Region2','Region3','Region3','Region2','Region1','Region3'],
 'Sector': ['Sector1',None,'Sector1','Sector3','Sector1','Sector1','Sector3','Sector2','Sector1','Sector2','Sector1','Sector3']})
```

What can I do next in order to create the grouped Bar chart?

Comment: How is `data_set.groupby(['Region','Grade'])['Grade'].count().plot(kind='bar')`?

Comment: Also, please share your actual data, not the pictures of them.

Comment: Hi @Abdou. It works in a different way. Instead of plotting a group of the grades for every single region, it plots a single bar for each grade in the region, that is: Instead of plotting `Region1(A,B,C,..), Region2(A,B,C,..)` 
It plots: `Region1(A), Region1(B),..., Region2(A), Region2(B),.....`

Comment: It's still not clear what you're after. Are you looking for just grade counts in each? If so, then all you need is `data_set.groupby('Region')['Grade'].count().plot(kind='bar')`.

Comment: This plots the overall count of grades in each region. 
I want to plot the count of each grade; A, B, C,.. in each region in a grouped bar chart.

Comment: `data_set.groupby(['Region','Grade'])['Grade'].count().unstack('Grade').fillna(0).plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)`?

Comment: This works very fine as stacked bars!
How to make the bars grouped instead of stacked?; you will have a group of bars for each region. it will look like the chart in the following link, where X axis is the `Regions` and the bars are the `Grades`.
[link](https://plot.ly/alpha/workspace/?fid=jackp:10657)

Comment: Just remove the `stacked` parameter then: `data_set.groupby(['Region','Grade'])['Grade'].count().unstac‌​k('Grade').fillna(0)‌​.plot(kind='bar')`?

Comment: Perfect! it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can get to your desired output in two ways. Either grouped:

```
data_set.groupby(['Region','Grade'])['Grade'].count().unstac‌​k('Grade').fillna(0)‌​.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: grouped bar plots]

or `stacked`:

```
data_set.groupby(['Region','Grade'])['Grade'].count().unstac‌​‌​k('Grade').fillna(‌​0)‌​.plot(kind='bar'‌​,sta‌​cked=True)
```

[image: stacked bar plots]

Thanks!